# Custom TableViewController, not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have search the web to learn how to create custom table view (because I want to hide the navigator bar for a specific view) and I am following each step. However, my result doesn't display the table.

Here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HallFameControllerViewController : UIViewController
    <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    NSArray *leaders;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *leaders;

@end
```

and my .m file

```
#import "HallFameControllerViewController.h"

@interface HallFameControllerViewController ()

@end

@implementation HallFameControllerViewController

@synthesize leaders;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    leaders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Player #1", @"Player #2", @"Player #3", nil];
}

- (void) viewDidUnload{

    self.leaders = nil;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [leaders count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.leaders objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

In my storyboard, I have created a ViewController and inside I have 1 label and 1 TableView. I have set Custom Class for my ViewController to "HallFameControllerViewController" and dataSource, delegate for Table View to "HallFameControllerViewController" as well. Results, Label is there but no table.

I have some printf() statements in side .m file, viewDidLoad() executed but cellForRowAtIndexPath() no!

What I am doing wrong here? In addition, what is cellIdentifier and why has set to "Cell" (automatically)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate, answered x times already. numberOfSectionsInTableView=1

Comment: @Daij-Djan There are more problems than just the wrong number of sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `UITableViewController`, not `UIViewController`. Then you don't need to add the `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate` protocols to your interface declaration.

You can use a plain view controller but its more work. You never actually added a UITableView anywhere. You simply implemented the table view methods (which you still need to do).

You need to update your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. Returning 0 is going to leave you an empty table, even after fixed the other issues.

So change this:

```
@interface HallFameControllerViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
```

to:

```
@interface HallFameControllerViewController : UITableViewController {
```

And change this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 0;
}
```

to:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```